# How to get the histogram fit function?

Tags: matlab

I want to have 7_order polynomial fit for my histogram, but I don’t want to plot it, I need the polynomial function with its coefficients to get new data. How can I get this?

Comment: From the doc: `p = polyfit(x,y,n)` returns the coefficients for a polynomial p(x) of degree n that is a best fit (in a least-squares sense) for the data in y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get *new data* from a polynomial function (that fits your original data points), you must first find the coefficients using `polyfit`.

In the example below, you calculate the 7th-degree polynomial that variable `p` holds and you generate *new data*, using `polyval`, so `y1` holds these data.

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi,10);
y = sin(x);
p = polyfit(x,y,7);

x1 = linspace(0,4*pi);
y1 = polyval(p,x1);
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation and the example, they are very helpful.

Comment: @Paris Welcome to SO! If you appreciate the help, could you please accept the answer?